# Why is the engine sputtering even when there is sufficient fuel?

Tags: engine, motorcycle, fuel-system, throttle

While kickstarting the motorcycle, the engine starts properly. But after travelling some distance, the engine sputters and turns off even when there is sufficient fuel. Then, after few raises to the throttle, the engine works properly.

The carburetor is working fine, which I recently checked.

What could be the reason behind this?

I own a BAJAJ CT100, which is a 100cc motorcycle.

Comment: You state there is "sufficient fuel" ... could it be there's *too much fuel*? (ie: flooding)

Comment: Could it be pre-ignition ? Or early timing?or vacuum line ?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 The fuel tank had 50% fuel.

Comment: @VijayMaximOff - What I stated has nothing to do with the amount of fuel in the tank. I'm wondering if the carburetor is putting too much fuel through to the engine and causing it to stall. How did you "check" the carb and know it's "working fine"? Allowing too much fuel through is as bad or worse than not enough.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I had the carb checked with the local mechanic